# Navigation Controller hides the iAd banner at the top of my view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, iad

I have two scenes that are connected with a Navigation Controller and all of my other scenes do not have it.

On the other scenes I have an iAd banner at the top of the view and each ViewController has the delegate logic.

When I add the navigation controller, it takes up the top of the view and hides the iAd banner. I would like the navigation controller to be placed under the iAd banner.

Is there a way for me to do this? Can it be done in StoryBoards or do I have to programmatically create the iAd banner in the ViewController?

Comment: Create an custom navigation bar view and add as a subview to your viewcontroller. set frame ypos bellow the iads view.

Comment: Take a look at apple sample code. It has many different examples of how to implement iad. You can find your answer in that. https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code to your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method:

```
navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, bannerHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - bannerHeight);
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the code in front of me at the moment but I will later today. Can I call "navigationController" from the ViewController class that I have embedded in a navigation controller? Or do I need to create a NavigationController class and add this to it and then assign the NavigationController in the storyboard the new class (right now it is set to the default UINavigationController class)?

Comment: call it directly from the parent where it is embedded

Comment: Sorry for the question -- still learning iOS dev. If I embed a ViewController with a NavigationController, does that make the NavigationController the parent of the ViewController?

Comment: if you mean you add it to the navigation stack, then yes, the UINavigationController will be its parent